# What is the type of the bytes of UInt32, Int32 and Float32?

Tags: javascript, types, floating-point, byte, dataview

To convert UInt32, Int32 and Float32 to bytes (and vice versa), I'm using **DataView**.

I was asking myself what is the **type** of the corresponding bytes : **Int8 or Uint8** ?

I would say Uint8 for Uint32 and Int8 for Int32, but what about Float32 ?

Comment: A byte is generally unsigned, so a byte is `UInt8`. A byte is a byte is a byte, so it doesn't matter for which conversion you use it. All the types you mention can be seen as a collection of bytes. How the specific combinations of bytes are interpreted makes these types signed or unsigned, integer or float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataView doesn't "convert UInt32, Int32 and Float32 to bytes", it converts JavaScript Numbers to bytes in UInt32, Int32, and Float32 formats. How the bytes are stored in a DataView and the underlying ArrayBuffer is an implementation detail.